# How do i fill color in each rectangle block using openCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, maze

I want to fill color in each cell of following image.i have used for loops to fill these boxes with pixel by pixel.when use filling borders also get colored that is main problem here.

These are dimensions of cell.

Width: 20px;

Height: 20px;

Border Width: 20px;

when neighbor cells are connected their border width will be 4 px.

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXgn9.jpg)

[Colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZwn8.jpg)

So i don't want to color borders only region of cell(white part) shold be colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image have three channels (R, G, B).

All the white blocks in image are white because they have 255 in pixels of all three channels.

To convert white blocks into red, first we read image matrix by using cv2 and then all the pixels having value 255 in channel-1 ("G") and channel-2 ("B") will be changed to 0. So, now we have pixel value 255 in channel-0 ("R") only. This way all white blocks of image gets changed to red colour block.

Two files are attached: 1. old_square.jpg       2. new_square.jpg

old_square.jpg have white colour square which are coloured into red colour, shown in new_square.jpg.

Check following script:

```
# libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np
import Image

# name of jpg image file
jpg_image_name = "old_square.jpg"

# reading jpg image and getting its matrix
jpg_image = cv2.imread(jpg_image_name)
jpg_image_mat = np.array(jpg_image)

# getting image features
pixel_value_to_replace = 255
rows, cols, channels = jpg_image_mat.shape

"""##########################################
An image have three channels (R, G, B). So,
putting 0 in other two channels to make image
red at white squares.
##########################################"""

# changing 255 to 0 in first channel
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if(jpg_image_mat[i, j, 1] == pixel_value_to_replace):
            jpg_image_mat[i, j, 1] = 0

# changing 255 to 0 in second channel
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if(jpg_image_mat[i, j, 2] == pixel_value_to_replace):
            jpg_image_mat[i, j, 2] = 0

# saving new modified matrix in image format
new_image = Image.fromarray(jpg_image_mat)
new_image.save("new_square.jpg")
```

[old_square.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2KxT.jpg)

[new_square.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPiqC.jpg)

Comment: thanks for your answer @sansingh but i dont want change color of border and white region should be colored only with different color rather than black.

Comment: Can I consider image posted by you as the image on which you have to work.

Comment: @Dash_25 you can work with the same logic, as I given in above script to get results..